# a prototype question in javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var Person =
{

    Create: function(name, age) {  
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    },
    showMe: function() {
        return " Person   Name: " + this.name + "  Age: " + this.age + " ";
    }
}; 

function New(aClass, aParams) {
    function new_() { 
        aClass.Create.apply(this, aParams);  
    };
    new_.prototype = aClass;   
    var obj = new new_();  
    return obj;
}
</script>
```

I don't quite understand the code above. Could someone tell me the meanings of Person, Create, showMe, New and new_? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Person` is an object with two functions - `Create` and `showMe`. In JavaScript, there are no classes, only objects, and this is how you write up an object - using 'Object Literal Notation' (the curly braces and functions/properties separated by commas).

`New` is a clever re-implementation of the `new` keyword. Instead of classes, javascript has prototypes, and instead of creating an instance of a class you create a copy of the prototype. In this case, if you passed `Person` to `New()`, it would used as the prototype in `new_.prototype = aClass`, and the rest of this function will return an object with the `Person` prototype, which means any changes to `Person` later on will be inherited into `obj` as well (unless `obj` has overridden them).

Answer (score 0):

```
`Person` -- a variable w/ 'parts' (used loosely) `Person.Create` and `Person.showMe'
     `Person.Create` -- function of `Person` that sets `Person.name` and `Person.age` to its arguments
     `Person.showMe` -- returns a string explaining values of `Person.name` and `Person.age`

`New` -- a function intended to instantiate new Person's thru prototypal (this is NOT class based) inheritenced
  `New._new` -- `New` uses this to get it done
```

Basically thru prototype inheritence, even though `Person` is only 'made' once, other 'versions' of it can be constructed in kind.  It can be used like this (try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/PBhCs/)

```
var Person =    {            
    Create: function(name, age) 
    {              
        this.name = name;            
        this.age = age
    },        

    showMe: function() 
    {            
        return " Person   Name: " + this.name + "  Age: " + this.age + " ";        
    }    
};         


function New(aClass, aParams) 
{        
    function new_() 
    {             
        aClass.Create.apply(this, aParams);          
    };
    new_.prototype = aClass;
    var obj = new new_();          
    return obj;    
}   

var a = New(Person, ['moo', 5]);
var b = New(Person, ['arf', 10]);
alert(a.showMe() + b.showMe());
```